# DRF: drf-nested-routers: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble displaying the `-detail` of a model using viewsets. I'm using the drf-nested-routers package for my urls.

Here is an example of `Course`s and a `Section` related to the course. (code is below)

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/CS250/",
        "course_code": "CS250",
        "sections_offered": [
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/CS250/sections/01/"
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/CS150/",
        "course_code": "CS150",
        "sections_offered": []
    }
]
```

I can navigate to `courses/CS250/sections` only if there was nothing, but once I create an object there I can no longer visit that endpoint, and I also cannot visit the URL of that object (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/CS250/sections/01/`) without getting this error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "section-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the 'lookup_field' attribute on this field.`

However, I can perfectly navigate to the url of a course (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/CS250/`)

/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, primary_key=True)

class Section(models.Model):
    section_number = models.CharField(default='01', max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    parent_course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name="sections_offered", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

/views.py

```
from . import models
from . import serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets

class CourseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.CourseSerializer
    queryset = models.Course.objects.all()

class SectionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.SectionSerializer
    queryset = models.Section.objects.all()
```

/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework_nested.relations import NestedHyperlinkedRelatedField
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class CourseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    sections_offered = NestedHyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='section-detail',
        parent_lookup_kwargs={'parent_course_pk': 'parent_course__pk'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = ("url", "course_code", "sections_offered",)

class SectionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Section
        fields = "__all__"
```

/urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from rest_framework_nested.routers import NestedSimpleRouter
from django.conf.urls import url, include

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'courses', views.CourseViewSet)
courses_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'courses', lookup='parent_course')
courses_router.register(r'sections', views.SectionViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(courses_router.urls)),
]
```

I figure that there might be a problem with the `SectionViewSet`, and that I may need to override the `retrieve()` and `list()` functions of the viewset, but am quite confused on how to approach this bug. It could be a problem with my urls too. I am a beginner, and I am not able to figure what I am doing wrong after many hours. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed not being able to view section-detail. I've fiddled with the code and modified the url field to SectionSerializer like this:

```
class SectionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        view_name='section-detail'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = models.Section
        fields = ('url', 'section_number', 'parent_course')
```

and am now able to navigate all endpoints. I'm not sure why, so I would really appreciate the explanation for this behavior.